# Using LINQ to SQL to create a database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I can use LINQ to create a database with some constituent tables using datacontext.createDatabase(). The problem is, each time I want to add a new table to the database and use this method, I have to delete the database first and then recreate the whole database with the additional table. This obviously blanks all the contents I had previously populated the tables with.

Is there a way to simply add the new table into the database without recreating it each time from scratch?

Answer (score 3):

I see two ways to do that

first

you can use the [ExceuteCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) -method of the DataContext to run some T-SQL statements for creating tables.

and second

you can use this hack function if you have mapped table type, as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/2bdfdde6-596e-4880-a3b3-3cb3ec365245)

```
public void CreateTable(Type linqTableClass)
{
    using (var tempDc = new DmsDataContext())
    {
        var metaTable = tempDc.Mapping.GetTable(linqTableClass);
        var typeName = "System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBuilder";
        var type = typeof(DataContext).Assembly.GetType(typeName);
        var bf = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod;
        var sql = type.InvokeMember("GetCreateTableCommand", bf, null, null, new[] { metaTable });
        var sqlAsString = sql.ToString();
        tempDc.ExecuteCommand(sqlAsString);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Your first option is what we used to do when we were using L2S. We created a bunch of statements out of programmatically created diff info on the model and executed that. Worked OK.

Answer (score 1):

The attached code creates a database, `dynamicDatabase11`, and a table, `books`.

```
public class MyDatabse : DataContext
{
    public Table<Bookss> Bookss;
    public MyDatabse(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}

[Table(Name = "Books")]
public class Bookss
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string Title;
    [Column]
    public string Rating;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateDatabase("DynamicDatabase11");
    }
    public static void CreateDatabase(string Dbname )
    {

        MyDatabse db = new MyDatabse("ConString"+Dbname+"");
        db.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
```

Comment: And how does this answer the OPs question?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature available at this point in time.

Not even in EF4 - at least not now...... these bits here ([Code-First Database Evolution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx)) didn't make it into the final EF 4.1 release.... :-(

I hear Microsoft's teams are working hard on a solution (EF "Migrations") - but it's still being worked on

Comment: You can, however, have a Sample Data class that will populate your database when recreated. I guess it might work for development.

Comment: @nosuchnick: that's in EF 4.1 code-first, right? Don't think Linq-to-SQL has anything similar..

Comment: Huh, probably. I'm using both Linq and EF for the first time now, with EF4.1.